# Crystal Report Viewer 2010

Tags: crystal-reports, c#-4.0

I'm using Crystal report 2010 with VS 2010, and i have 2 web projects, the first is the one that my organization works with and the second is a dummy one - this is for test only -, my problem is when dealing with charts or pictures, every thing OK in the second project, but in the first one charts and pictures are displayed very will in crystal report designer, and preview, but nothing is displayed at run time. the environment of the 2 projects are identical (the same referenced DLLs, and from the same location "Local Folder", the same binding method "Objects", the same registered and add "Keys, and Assemblies" in the web.config).

kindly, note that one of the differences between the 2 projects is that the working one was created after installing Crystal Reports 2010 for VS, and the primary one was created before the installation.

please, does any body has an idea where is the mistaken part, or where I'm i suppose to search about the malfunctioning configuration, or ...... etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to bother you all the previous period,

we discovered the issue source, it is an htppModule related to our security module, we do not know what is cause of this conflict tell now, but at least we knew the source, every thing is OK, if the registration of this httpModule removed from the web.config.

Sorry again, and most thanks.